# $rootScope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following instruction in a file called loginCtrl.js and I cannot make $rootScope to hold the value of vm.userEmail.

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($timeout, $q, $log, $rootScope /*$auth*/,   $location, $mdToast) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.loginMessage = '';
    vm.login = function(){
        $auth.login({
            $rootScope: vm.userEmail,
            password: vm.userPassword
    })  
  }
});
```

$rootScope would help me in this conditional whenever this particular user gets connected.

```
if ($rootScope == 'y_y@hotmail.com') {
        data = [1,2,3,4]
    } else {
        data = [5,6,7,8]
    }
```

Any ideas, suggestions or corrections are welcome ;)

Comment: Are you trying to override `$rootScope`?

Comment: I don't know if by overriding it could make to hold the value but if that's possible please let me know how to do it. Or any other idea of how to make my solution to get working.

Comment: you cannot override `$rootScope` , its a angularjs defined variable, overriding its value will create unusual behaviour. so if you need a variable just creating one under `$rootScope.newVal` and use it.

Comment: hey there! I tried to modify this variable with a new variable: $rootScope.vmusername : vm.userEmail, 

However, the console throws an error where it says that an unexpected token was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rootscope is like an application context. So you can add new value to the application context. Below is your working code.
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($timeout, $q, $log, $rootScope /*$auth*/,   $location, $mdToast) 
{

```
var vm = this;
vm.loginMessage = '';
vm.login = function(){
    $auth.login({
        $rootScope.userEmail : vm.userEmail,
        password: vm.userPassword
})
```

}
});

Now you can use read $rootScope.userEmail from anywhere in the application.

if ($rootScope.userEmail == 'y_y@hotmail.com') 
{

```
    data = [1,2,3,4]
} else {
    data = [5,6,7,8]`enter code here`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$rootScope = someValue;
```

use

```
$rootScope.someValue= someValue;
```

For second part your code try:

you should watch change on `$rootSchope.someValue`

something like:

```
$rootScope.$watch('$rootScope.someValue', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue='y_y@hotmail.com') {
        data = [1,2,3,4]
    }
});
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried the following:

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($timeout, $q, $log, $rootScope /*$auth*/, $location, $mdToast) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.loginMessage = '';
    vm.login = function(){
        $auth.login({
            $rootScope.username: vm.userEmail,
            password: vm.userPassword
        })

Then I tried my code back but it didn't work.

Comment: @AlejandroRamos: where are you trying to access this `$rootScope.username` ?

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me. I want to get access to $rootScope.username into another file called siteCtrl.js to make this conditional to work: 

if ($rootScope == 'y_y@hotmail.com') {
        data = [1,2,3,4]
}